# Can you rebuild the special units from the Powerful Lords (preorder) DLC?

Tags: warlock-master-arcane

With the preorder of the game come 2 special units, the Blade Master and the Imp-Advisor, which spawn at your city if you select them as perks when starting a new game.

**If those Units die, can they be rebuilt somehow?**